# Get everything after Slash c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get everything before the / character in a string. Some example strings are below.

```
var url = dr.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"u_0_3\"]/div/h1/a"));
            foreach (var item in url)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("href").ToString().Contains("https://www.facebook.com/"))
                {
                    listBox4.Items.Add("here");
                }
            }
```

the href is like that = "http://facebook.com/xxx"
want the xxx which is username want to get it alone in my listbox without the rest of the url

Comment: `item = item.Replace(@"http://facebook.com/", string.Empty);`?

Comment: Don't use strings, create a `Uri` instance and use the methods/properties on there.

Comment: simple and dirty way is 'string[] strArray = strString.Split('/'); strWantedString = strArray[strArray.Count];'

Answer (score -1):

If you're at the point where you've got the string you want to work with, here are two ways to do this:

**Split the string by `/` and take the last part**

```
var stringToProcess = "https://www.facebook.com/ProfileName";
var partsOfString = stringToProcess.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var profileName = partsOfString.Last();
```

**Use the `Uri` class to extract the last part**

```
var stringToProcess = "https://www.facebook.com/ProfileName";
var stringToProcessAsUri = new Uri(stringToProcess);
var profileNameFromUri = stringToProcessAsUri.Segments.Last();
```

This is the "strictly better" way as it will give you a clean result even if the profile address has a query string attached to it, i.e:

```
var stringToProcess = "https://www.facebook.com/ProfileName?abc=def";
var stringToProcessAsUri = new Uri(stringToProcess);
var profileNameFromUri = stringToProcessAsUri.Segments.Last();
```

You'll still have the variable `profileNameFromUri` returned containing only `ProfileName`